# js variable scope question

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i make data overwrite results variable ?

```
var ajax = {
    get : {
        venues : function(search){
            var results = "@";
            $.getJSON("http://x.com/some.php?term="+search+"&callback=?",function(data){ results = data; });
            return results;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Not a scope problem. You need to understand how asynchronous code and callbacks work. See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021114/javascript-jquery-variables-not-giving-expected-values, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092563/scope-of-variable-in-javascript-problem for others that have fallen into the same trap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` *is* overwriting `results`, just after `results` has been returned.

You can use the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function instead of `getJSON`, since [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is just shorthand for

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

and then also set `async` to `false`, so that the call will block.

However, in your case this won't work, because JSONP requests (with `"?callback=?"`) cannot be synchronous.

The other (better) option is to have whatever code is dependent on the `results` return value get called by the `success` callback.

So, instead of something like this:

```
var results = ajax.get.venues('search');
$('#results').html(translateResults(results));
```

Maybe something like this:

```
ajax.get.venues('search', function (results) {
    $('#results').html(translateResults(results));
});

venues = function (search, callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://x.com/some.php?term="+search+"&callback=?",
              function(data){
                  callback(data); 
              });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. `results` *does* get overwritten, but only later, after the function has already exited, because the callback is executed when the request has finished.

You would have to make the Ajax call synchronous using `sync: true` (this is usually not a good idea, just mentioning it for completeness's sake) or restructure your code flow so it doesn't depend on the `return` value any more, but everything you need to do gets done in the callback function.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a scope problem.  It's because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous; `results` is returned before `$.getJSON` finishes.  Try making a callback for `$.getJSON` to call when it's done.

```
function JSON_handler(data){
    // do stuff...
}

$.getJSON("http://x.com/some.php?term="+search+"&callback=?", JSON_handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put the logic you want to run in a callback.

```
    var ajax = {
      get : {
        venues : function(search, fnCallback){
            var results = "@";
            $.getJSON("http://x.com/some.php?term="+search+"&callback=?",
                function(data){ 
                    // success
                    results = data; 
                    (typeof fnCallback == 'function') && fnCallback(data);
                });
            return results;
        }
    }
};

ajax.get.venues(term, function(result){
    // Do stuff with data here :)
})
```

functional programming can be fun.